# how can i get links from WebKitBrowser

Tags: .net, winforms, webkit

I use WebKitBrowser (webket.net), I hope that when I click on a link inside WebKitBrowser I can customize how to handle this link (some links I want to specify the machine's default browser), so I want to know where I can intercept this event.

I checked the webkitbrowser class, did not find the right event, it seems in the webviewclass, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to get a list of links you can use

```
WebKit.DOM.NodeList links = Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("link");
foreach (WebKit.DOM.Element link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("href").CompareTo(link_addr) == 0) {
         // Do Your Thing
    }
}
```

you could probably use the Navigating event to control where each link goes.
If it's a link to open on your program do nothing - otherwise do

```
 e.Cancel = true;
```

and then send the link address to the system's browser